# Include .htaccess according to directory

Tags: apache

I need to include a htaccess dynamically by example below.
But, wildcards in Include are not allowed. Any ideas? :)

```
<Directory "/Users/josh/dev/.*/www">

   AllowOverride None
   RewriteBase /
   Include /Users/josh/dev/^(.*)$/.htaccess

</Directory>
```

Comment: This is not how `.htaccess` files are used. You do not include them or have to include them. The http server automatically find them if they are placed inside that directory. I suggest you read the documentation, this is well explained: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: But I need it as it is explained above, since I need to expand the htaccess, but without changing it directly.

Comment: Why can't you simply place rules in the host configuration as you already do? Those will automatically get mixed with the "dynamic" rules in `.htaccess` style files...

Comment: Sounds like a typical case where it makes sense that you explain what you are trying to do here in your question. Instead of explain how you think that you might be able to do it.

Comment: Putting just  `RewriteBase /` into this directory tag will just send error 500.

Comment: `RewriteBase /` is not allowed in `Directory` context. That is clearly documented. You _do_ read the documentation, don't you?

Comment: It is allowed in Directory, but not allowed in Virtualhost... Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, indeed you are right. So question is why you get a status 500. What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: Just:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error, since it can't find the correct path for rewrite. 

If I add RewriteBase / directly into .htaccess, it works. Quite strange... but it works.

Comment: Could be an issue with different roots in the virtual file tree. I suggest you enable rewrite logging and monitor the exact steps going on in your rewrite engine.